# Python with embedded call to mpirun

Tags: python, c++, mpi

I am trying to run some parallel optimization using PyOpt. The tricky part is that within my objective function, I want to run a C++ code using mpi as well.

My python script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
# Standard Python modules
import os, sys, time, math
import subprocess


# External Python modules
try:
    from mpi4py import MPI
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    myrank = comm.Get_rank()
except:
    raise ImportError('mpi4py is required for parallelization')

# Extension modules
from pyOpt import Optimization
from pyOpt import ALPSO

# Predefine the BashCommand
RunCprogram = "mpirun -np 2 CProgram" # Parallel C++ program


######################### 
def objfunc(x):

    f = -(((math.sin(2*math.pi*x[0])**3)*math.sin(2*math.pi*x[1]))/((x[0]**3)*(x[0]+x[1])))

    # Run CProgram 
    os.system(RunCprogram) #where the mpirun call occurs

    g = [0.0]*2
    g[0] = x[0]**2 - x[1] + 1
    g[1] = 1 - x[0] + (x[1]-4)**2

    time.sleep(0.01)
    fail = 0
    return f,g, fail

# Instantiate Optimization Problem 
opt_prob = Optimization('Thermal Conductivity Optimization',objfunc)
opt_prob.addVar('x1','c',lower=5.0,upper=1e-6,value=10.0)
opt_prob.addVar('x2','c',lower=5.0,upper=1e-6,value=10.0)
opt_prob.addObj('f')
opt_prob.addCon('g1','i')
opt_prob.addCon('g2','i')

# Solve Problem (DPM-Parallelization)
alpso_dpm = ALPSO(pll_type='DPM')
alpso_dpm.setOption('fileout',0)
alpso_dpm(opt_prob)
print opt_prob.solution(0)
```

I run that code using:

```
mpirun -np 20 python Script.py
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
[user:28323] *** Process received signal ***
[user:28323] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[user:28323] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[user:28323] Failing at address: (nil)
[user:28323] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3ccfc0f500]
[user:28323] *** End of error message ***
```

I figure that the 2 different `mpirun` calls (the one calling the python script and the one within the script) are conflicting with each other. 
Any lead on how to solve that?

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you exchange data between the python processes using mpi communications or are you just using `mpi4py` to run multiple isolated instances. If this is the case, you may consider using the `subprocess` module in python to spawns multiple thread, each of which can call an `mpirun` instance (using `subprocess.Popen`). I do this frequently and have had no problems. If you're running the `Script.py` across multiple machine this may not be possible...

Answer (score 3):

See [Calling mpi binary in serial as subprocess of mpi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090085/calling-mpi-binary-in-serial-as-subprocess-of-mpi-application) : the safiest way to go is to use [`MPI_Comm_spawn()`](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php) . Take a look at [this manager-worker example](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node98.htm) for instance.

A quick fix would be to use `subprocess.Popen` as signaled by @EdSmith. Yet, notice that the default behavior of `subprocess.Popen` use the parent's environment. My guess is that it is the same for `os.system()`. Unfortunately, some environnement variables are added by mpirun, depending on the MPI implementation, such as `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` or `OMPI_MCA_orte_ess_num_procs`. To see these environment variables, type `import os ; print os.environ` in an mpi4py code and in a basic python shell. These environment variables may lead to a failure of the subprocess. So i had to add a line to get rid of them...which is rather dirty... It boils down to :

```
    args = shlex.split(RunCprogram)
    env=os.environ
    # to remove all environment variables with "MPI" in it...rather dirty...
    new_env = {k: v for k, v in env.iteritems() if "MPI" not in k}

    #print new_env
    # shell=True : watch for security issues...
    p = subprocess.Popen(RunCprogram,shell=True, env=new_env,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    result="process myrank "+str(myrank)+" got "+p.stdout.read()
    print result
```

Complete test code, ran by `mpirun -np 2 python opti.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
# Standard Python modules
import os, sys, time, math
import subprocess
import shlex


# External Python modules
try:
    from mpi4py import MPI
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    myrank = comm.Get_rank()
except:
    raise ImportError('mpi4py is required for parallelization')

# Predefine the BashCommand
RunCprogram = "mpirun -np 2 main" # Parallel C++ program


######################### 
def objfunc(x):

    f = -(((math.sin(2*math.pi*x[0])**3)*math.sin(2*math.pi*x[1]))/((x[0]**3)*(x[0]+x[1])))

    # Run CProgram 
    #os.system(RunCprogram) #where the mpirun call occurs
    args = shlex.split(RunCprogram)
    env=os.environ
    new_env = {k: v for k, v in env.iteritems() if "MPI" not in k}

    #print new_env
    p = subprocess.Popen(RunCprogram,shell=True, env=new_env,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    result="process myrank "+str(myrank)+" got "+p.stdout.read()
    print result



    g = [0.0]*2
    g[0] = x[0]**2 - x[1] + 1
    g[1] = 1 - x[0] + (x[1]-4)**2

    time.sleep(0.01)
    fail = 0
    return f,g, fail

print objfunc([1.0,0.0])
```

Basic worker, compiled by `mpiCC main.cpp -o main` :

```
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);    
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);  
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);  

    if(rank==0){
        std::cout<<" size "<<size<<std::endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;

}
```